# How to feed the output from vr-sink (video viewer) into Alexnet in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, simulink

I'm working on a project using MATLAB and Simulink in which I have an output video from VR-Sink, which I gave as input to video viewer. How can I use this output from VR-Sink into Alexnet for performing deep learning on the data? Is there any specific function that can be used?

I know that the output from VR-sink should be a 227 x 227 x 3 video sequence, and I was able to get it correctly.

I presume there might be an inbuilt function for performing such a data transfer, but due to lack of documentation regarding the actual implementation and functions based on Alexnet, I am not able to figure out the how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer for this question that I asked previously. 
As the output from the "Video Viewer" block can be stored as a .avi file using "To multimedia File" block provided by Computer Vision Toolbox, I was able to convert this video sequence file to frames using VLC media player. 
These frames were stored as images and were declared as variables using imread(). A while loop can be created to generate a sequence of the frames and the variable can be provided as input to the neural network for recognition